# How to hide suggestions on known words in Visual Studio Code?

Tags: visual-studio-code, vscode-extensions

Suggestions are very useful, but sometimes they're annoying.

I want to hide suggestions when what I typed is a known word in the language or in the current document.

E.g.: Since I used the word `elapsed` in a document, every single `else` I typed after it selected `elapsed`. Very annoying. Since `else` is a known word, I want the suggestions disappear, so when I hit `ENTER` the final word is that what I typed. This is a case; there are a lot of cases.

Other editors hide suggestions on known words (e.g.: Kate).

Tuning `"editor.quickSuggestionsDelay"` doesn't help, because frequently I stop to think and suggestions will appear anyway.
`"editor.acceptSuggestionOnEnter": false` doesn't help too; I've tried it but I'm not productive using `TAB` instead of `ENTER`.

I also tried `"editor.wordBasedSuggestions": false`, but this is not what I want. It hides every known word, but I want to select known words if I didn't type one.

I would like an option like `"editor.hideSuggestionsOnKnownWord": true`, but I could not find nothing similar in vscode.

Is there an option or an extension to do that?